# Sort grep output numerical of value after last space

Tags: python, awk, grep

after starting grep, I get following output:

```
2.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 16
3.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 15
4.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 26
5.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 22
6.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 12
7.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 3
8.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 19
9.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 3
10.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 7
11.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 3
12.txt:;Number of recorded Units: 35
```

For example I have installed gawk, but I don't know how code it for that.
I wish output like this:
I have gawk, can someone please provide:

```
7.txt:;Number of recorded Units:    3
9.txt:;Number of recorded Units:    3
11.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   3
10.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   7
6.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   12
3.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   15
2.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   16
1.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   18
8.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   19
5.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   22
4.txt:;Number of recorded Units:   26
12.txt:;Number of recorded Units:  35
```

(the order of entries (here 3) same values is not important).
Or is there any other tool/program better suitable (Python script for example)?

Comment: take a look at `man sort`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try:

```
..yourGrep|sort -n -t':' -k3
```

Comment: Thank you, but, sorry, I forgot to say, that I am on windows 7, so this does not work here.

Comment: If you're on Windows 7, how do `awk` and `grep` even work?

Comment: I don't know anymore exactly, longer times ago I installed gnu utilities on windows.

Comment: Ahh, just found out, windows use the "internal" cmd sort command, and if I use the sort cmd from gnu utilities, it works. But I had to change -t':' to -t":". Thank you Kent. Anyway I would be interested, how it could be solved by (g)awk.